How to access environmental variables when executing a python-behave test?
I am trying to set up a behave test for my app and I need to access many different environmental variables during the execution.
For example, I have code that checks if the ENVIRONMENT is local, dev or prod.
I saw that in the environment.py file I can access parameters passed to the command line like: behave -t qa -D ENVIRONMENT=local
And access it in the before_ funcitons like this: context.config.userdata['ENVIRONMENT']
But so far I was unable to turn that into an environment variable for my test's execution.
Am I missing something or that is more like a feature request?
Thank you!

Okay, I found a simple way to do it
ENVIRONMENT=local JOB=foo behave
Not sure why this works better than the other case, but here it is!
